# How do you simulate hardware in Python?

Tags: python, mips

Kind of confusing title but my assignment is to write a 4 stage MIPS processor (IF, ID, EX, WB) in a high level language (I know python best probably). Beyond the difficulty I haven't even started to try yet of caches and stalls, how do you take code that is supposed to be running in parallel and make that sequential? Consider this code snippit.

```
pc = 0x0
IFinput, IDinput, EXinput, WBinput = None, None, None, None
while True:
    IFinput = self.memory.getInstruction(pc)
    if not IFinput: #No more instructions
        break

    self.IF.giveInput(IFinput)
    self.ID.giveInput(IDinput)
    self.EX.giveInput(EXinput)
    self.WB.giveInput(WBinput)

    instruction += 0x4
    clock += 1

    IDinput = self.IF.getOutput(clock)
    EXinput = self.ID.getOutput(clock)
    WBinput = self.EX.getOutput(clock)
    result  = self.WB.getOutput(clock)
result.printToFile()
```

I'm trying to break apart the input and output of the thing into two different stages such that I dont "cheat" the hardware by getting output back before the "clock += 1" command executes. Is that the right way to implement this? Are there any python libraries that were written that are suited to this task? Thanks.

Comment: Consider purpose-specific languages like VHDL or Verilog; possibly with a combination/extension such as [PyHVL](http://pyhvl.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: @user2864740 as much as I would like to use a hardware language, the server I'm working on (which I do not have root on) does not include any of these :(

Comment: Shame. What about a [local] virtual machine/environment running whatever tooling is required to sanely accomplish the task?

Comment: Anyway - if I were starting this from *scratch*, and trying to emulate hw lines, with a "generic" high-level language, I would likely design the system around "reactive" clock ticks. Since it's a primitive simulator I would not factor in any form of concurrency or parallelism beyond such. Make sure to not read too much into the assignment/task.

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there. The function names are a bit confusing - I'd prefer `capture()` and `update()` instead. `memory.getIstruction()` shall definitely be hidden inside `IF.capture()` (IF job *is* to fetch an instruction, right?). PC update also seem to belong to IF stage.

A "no more instructions" condition doesn't happen in real life, and shall be abandoned. A right way to break the loop is EX stage to raise an exception (say, on a reserved instruction from an illegal range; keep in mind that other exceptions may and will be raised legitimately).

Otherwise, looks good as a starting point.

Answer (score 1):

It was suggested in the comments to use some special purpose language like VHDL or so, but I guess that for some simple exercise, where speed probably does not matter, using Python is perfectly fine.

Your code looks almost ok, I just don't understand why your `getOutput` functions need `clock` as an input, since supposedly the functionality of a block is time-invariant and only depends on its inputs. I think the only trick you need to do is to make two versions of every register that exists in your processor, one set representing their current state, and one representing the state after one click tick. All functions that simulate your hardware should then only use the 'current' registers as inputs, and save their outputs to the 'next' registers. Then at the end of the loop, you copy all the next registers into the current ones and you start all over again. Something like this:

```
pc = 0
IF2ID_cur, ID2EX_cur, EX2WB_cur = 0 # values of registers after a reset

while True:
    instruction = memory[pc]
    IF2ID_nxt = simulate_IF(instruction)
    ID2EX_nxt = simulate_ID(IF2ID_cur)
    EX2WB_nxt = simulate_EX(ID2EX_cur)
    result =    simulate_WB(EX2WB_cur)

    pc += 1
    IF2ID_cur, ID2EX_cur, EX2WB_cur = IF2ID_nxt, ID2EX_nxt, EX2WB_nxt
```

Note that in this way, all 'simulate' functions only use the current register values and not any of the values of the next clock cycle. You can therefore change the order in which they are executed without changing the results, as if they were all running in parallel.

Comment: The reason for passing clock to "get result" is that whether or not a result has been produced is dependent on how many cycles have elapsed? For example, if an instruction enters the EX stage at 5, then it will take 2-20 cycles depending on of its a ALU op, FP op, etc. Furthermore I can't be sure exactly when things will be done, because even after the ex operation "completes", it may be stalled waiting for the WB port to be free

Comment: Ah, you didn't say that, I assumed that all stages were single cycle. But it that case, you could add a queue to every item with the appropriate length, no need to pass the absolute clock number.

Comment: @SetSlapShot I would *really* look into a reactive setup - i.e. callbacks that are executed only on certain conditions (such as the line state on the clock or after x ticks).

Answer (score 1):

Consider purpose-specific languages like VHDL or Verilog; possibly with a combination/extension such as [PyHVL](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2864740/user2864740) or [Cocotb](http://potentialventures.github.io/cocotb/) ..

.. however, if this *must* be created from scratch and/or a pure-Python implementation, consider using the same concepts as in the high-level hardware languages. In particular, consider a *reactive* design. Both Verilog and VHDL support this notion - where a change to input, such as the clock, drives the behaviors and new output state.

Each "reactive callback" then simply takes in the input state and emits a particular output state in isolation from the other components. Dependencies are then established *only* by state changes and reactive triggers around changes.

Things that might be used in triggers/guards:

- Line or data change states
- Signaling events
- Cycle counts (e.g. minimum, after, random)

Comment: There's a descendant of [PyHVL](http://pyhvl.sourceforge.net/) called [Cocotb](http://cocotb.com) which is being actively maintained and provides various advantages and improvements - for example it works with both VHDL and Verilog.  Worth considering for new designs.