# fetch and decode instruction located at X address with c

Tags: c, cpu-registers, instructions

I want to fetch and decode a instruction at address X. After that I want to increment the address by 4 and then execute the decoded instruction. The registers are 32 bit big endian. I am not asking for a solution, more a pointer or tips on how to do this in C, or if any of you know some good guides to follow.

Comment: The "address" will be implemented using a pointer to `char`.  Your simulated "instructions" will live in an array of char.

Comment: okay, so lets say reg 63 work as the program counter how do i call that and the use it as pointer for the other instructuions

Comment: I believe you are looking for this function to jump to the address http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fseek.3.html and this one to read https://linux.die.net/man/3/fread (the address is automatically updated after reading).

Comment: First, design this on paper, with pictures and basic flow. Then translate it into whatever language you are familiar with, or pseudo-code, or just some computer-like language you invent. Make sure it works, by logical inspection; that's good enough. Only then do you translate that to "C". Something like this can be implemented with a very small subset of the language -- perhaps your problem is in the first few steps. If you still have problems translating some constructs into "C", come back with your pseudo code, and someone will help you.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want assembly for this, not C. You could link assembly code into a C program, but you shouldn't write that in C.

Comment: dealing with the actual instruction set of the processor? No way you want C for that. ASM all the way

Comment: You can write a full processor simulator in "C", or even a higher-level language (e.g., Python). Implementing a simple processor in high-level language is a common assignment in CS classes. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23026095/how-do-you-simulate-hardware-in-python